# Using the predict function from R 'caret' package

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I am trying to run the command below:

```
predDF <- data.frame(pred.RF, pred.SVM, pred.KNN, pred.NB, pred.BGM, pred.MARS, pred.GAM, pred.SGD, satisfied = pr.out.incl.score.val.2.df.x$satisfied)

modelStack1 <- train(satisfied ~ ., predDF, method = "glm")

testPredLevelOne <- data.frame(pred.RF.3, pred.SVM.3, pred.KNN.3, pred.NB.3, pred.BGM.3, pred.MARS.3, pred.GAM.3, pred.SGD.3, satisfied = pr.out.incl.score.val.3.df.x$satisfied)

combPred1 <- predict(modelStack1, testPredLevelOne)
```

The data frame `predDF` has the 4888 observations (rows), and the data frame `testPredLevelOne` has 2632 observations (rows). From what I understand, this difference in the number of observations shouldn't matter when I execute `combPred1 <- predict(modelStack1, testPredLevelOne)`. But when I execute the line, I am getting the error below:

```
Warning message:
'newdata' had 2632 rows but variables found have 4888 rows
```

How can I solve this error?

For more reference, when I do `str(testPredLevelOne)`, the output is below:

```
 str(testPredLevelOne)
'data.frame':   2632 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ pred.RF.3  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ pred.SVM.3 : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ pred.KNN.3 : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ pred.NB.3  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ pred.BGM.3 : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ pred.MARS.3: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ pred.GAM.3 : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ pred.SGD.3 : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ satisfied  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Thank you,

Comment: Can you show the output of `str(testPredLevelOne)`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment, I updated my post as par your request

Comment: Have you tried to set the column names the same for the both data frames?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the new data with similar column names as your train data. It is not like sklearn in python.

For example:

```
library(caret)
idx = sample(nrow(iris),100)
v1_train = iris$Sepal.Length[idx]
v2_train = iris$Sepal.Width[idx]
v3_train = iris$Petal.Length[idx]
y_train = iris$Petal.Width[idx]

v1_test = iris$Sepal.Length[-idx]
v2_test = iris$Sepal.Width[-idx]
v3_test = iris$Petal.Length[-idx]
y_test = iris$Petal.Width[-idx]

predDF <- data.frame(v1_train,v2_train,v3_train,y = y_train)
modelStack1 <- train(y ~ ., predDF, method = "glm")

testPredLevelOne <- data.frame(v1_test,v2_test,v3_test,y = y_test)
combPred1 <- predict(modelStack1, testPredLevelOne)

Warning message:
'newdata' had 50 rows but variables found have 100 rows
```

We check the length and values of the prediction and it is simply that from the training:

```
length(combPred1)
[1] 100
table(combPred1 == modelStack1$finalModel$fitted.values)
TRUE 
 100
```

If we rename the column names of the test to the same as train data, it will not cause an error:

```
colnames(testPredLevelOne) = colnames(predDF)
combPred1 <- predict(modelStack1, testPredLevelOne)
 length(combPred1)
[1] 50
```